# Why is Salsa music counted in 8 if it is in 4/4 time?

Tags: theory, sheet-music

The wikipedia page shows salsa notated in 4/4 time and the clave (which marks the rhythm) is written as 16th notes:

**1** ee and **aa** 2 ee **and** aa 3 ee **and** aa **4** ee and aa

but most Salsa teachers seem to count it in 8 or two groups of 4 like this not using 16th notes at all but rather as 8th notes.

**1** and 2 **and** 3 and **4** and 5 and **6** and **7** and 8

or

**1** and 2 **and** 3 and **4** and 1 and **2** and **3** and 4

Comment: Dancers almost always count in eight beat phrases without particular regard to the notated musical meter.

Answer (score 6):

Dancers count by steps rather than by measures, and salsa typically features eight steps per phrase (two measures of 4/4 time). See [this similar question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-many-beats-are-to-dance-salsa-music-How-do-you-count-it) for details:

> [In] each 4/4 measure, a dancer steps three times, either left/right/left or right/left/right. That means you need another measure to get back to the same foot. For that reason, it makes a lot of sense to count 2 measures. Mostly salsa dance patterns span 2, sometimes 4, measures.

Comment: Thank you. However, It isn't only dancers. Musicians that teach salsa also divide the "clave" over 2 measures instead of over one measure. The Wikipedia page for "Salsa music" shows it in one measure only using 16th notes.

Answer (score -1):

The shortest answer is: it isn't by musicians. There are 4 beats per clave. Dancers count in 8 because it's easier to count 'one two three four' than 'one and two and'.